# Condor output file updating

Tags: c++, output, condor

I'm running several simulations using Condor and have coded the program so that it outputs a progress status in the console. This is done at the end of a loop where it simply prints the current time (this can also be percentage or elapsed time). The code looks something like this:

```
printf("START");
while (programNeedsToRum) {

   // Run code repetitive code...

   // Print program status update
   printf("[%i:%i:%i]\r\n", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
printf("FINISH");
```

When executing normally (i.e. in the terminal/cmd/bash) this works fine, but the condor nodes don't seem to `printf()` the status. Only once the simulation has finished, all the status updates have been outputted to the file but then it's no longer of use. My *.sub file that I submit to condor looks like this:

```
universe = vanilla
executable = program
output = out/out-$(Process)
error = out/err-$(Process)
queue 100
```

When submitted the program executes (this is confirmed in `condor_q`) and the output files contain this:

```
START
```

Only once the program has finished running its corresponding output file shows (example):

```
START
[0:3:4]
[0:8:13]
[0:12:57]
[0:18:44]
FINISH
```

Whilst the program executes, the output file only contains the `START` text. So I came to the conclusion that the file is not updated if the node executing program is busy. So my question is, is there a way of updating the output files manually or gather any information on the program's progress in a better way?

Thanks already

Max

Comment: Are your execute nodes using a shared filesystem, or do you have `ShouldTransferFiles` set to TRUE?

Comment: I followed my University's guide and it stated that for their system, `should_transfer_files` is always set to `TRUE` unless specified otherwise. I'll re-run with that option just to make sure.

Comment: TRIED IT: When specifying the `should_transfer_files` and the `when_to_transfer_output` values, files created by `stringstream` (through C++) can't be accessed/created anymore. It didn't work, even when I removed the entire `stringstream` and only left in the console output with all condor values set as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is use the streaming output options. See the `stream_error` and `stream_output` options you can pass to `condor_submit` as outlined here: http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/current/condor_submit.html

By default, HTCondor stores stdout and stderr locally on the execute node and transfers them back to the submit node on job completion. Setting `stream_output` to `TRUE` will ask HTCondor to instead stream the output as it occurs back to the submit node. You can then inspect it as it happens.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I used a few years ago to solve this problem.  It uses `condor_chirp` which is used to transfer files from the execute host to the submitter.  I have a python script that executes the program I really want to run, and redirects its output to a file.  Then, periodically, I send the output file back to the submit host.

Here's the Python wrapper, `stream.py`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import os,sys,time

 os.environ['PATH'] += ':/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/condor/bin'
 # make sure the file exists
 open(sys.argv[1], 'w').close()

 pid = os.fork()
 if pid == 0:
    os.system('%s >%s' % (' '.join (sys.argv[2:]), sys.argv[1]))
 else:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        os.system('condor_chirp put %s %s' % (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[1]))
        try:
            os.wait4(pid, os.WNOHANG)
        except OSError:
            break
```

And my submit script.  The problem ran `sh hello.sh`, and redirected the output to `myout.txt`:

```
 universe                = vanilla
 executable              = C:\cygwin\bin\python.exe
 requirements            = Arch=="INTEL" && OpSys=="WINNT60" && HAS_CYGWIN==TRUE
 should_transfer_files   = YES
 transfer_input_files    = stream.py,hello.sh
 arguments               = stream.py myout.txt sh hello.sh
 transfer_executable     = false
```

It does send the output in its entirety, so take that in to account if you have a lot of jobs running at once.  Currently, its sending the output every 10 seconds .. you may want to adjust that.

Answer (score 1):

with `condor_tail` you can view the output of a running process.
to see stdout just add the job-ID (and -f if you want to follow the output and see the updates immediately. Example:

```
condor_tail 314.0 -f
```