# Is it possible to retrieve the output of python scripts in HTCondor?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, condor

I would like to run some python scripts that return some dictionaries on a cluster managed by HTCondor. I run the same on another cluster running MPI/Slurm and mpi4py and I was able to collect the output without saving files and transfer them to the main node. I cannot understand how to do it in HTCondor (even using python wrappers).

Is it possible to retrieve the output of python scripts in HTCondor? 
Do i need to use the `schedd.retrieve("ClusterId == %d" % cluster)` command? if so an example will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just trying to do the same. Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: At the end I gave up and create DAGs after saving intermediated files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may specify a file to which you want to save your stdout in your submit file (see also [Condor output file updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157442/condor-output-file-updating)).

You can watch the output using `htcondor_tail` (not sure what the equivalent is in the python api).

Slightly off-topic: If you run python you can also use e.g. Dask to do your remote python stuff (see also [Dask with HTCondor scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488603/dask-with-htcondor-scheduler/57526723))

Comment: As you suggested I transitioned to dask-jobque to handle the jobs on top of HTCondor. It works really nice and make it easier to retrieve the output of the jobs.